Is it possible to have Azure Application Insights metrics without incurring Log Analytics cost?
I have some Azure Function Apps running with Application Insights configured but I'm getting a very high cost from Log Analytics because apparently all these metrics become log entries that are ingested by Log Analytics, even if I never use Log Analytics directly.
The main problem is that the company has Enterprise Splunk configured and we are routing our logs to it via Diagnostic Settings. So essentially we're now paying twice for the same logs, once in Splunk and once in Log Analytics.
As of Sep/2024 is there a way to have Application Insights Metrics without incurring Log Analytics costs?

Hi, Application insights started using Azure log analytics as default log storage from last year. You cannot avoid this. Need to have a log analytics workspace for an application insights.
Also check if you log analytics is connected to a vm (sys and event logs) or storage account. You should disconnect if these logs are not important for you.
I understand that you might be using Appinsights dependencies in your code for logging. Check if you can do this splunk directly instead.

Application Insights relies on Azure Log Analytics as its primary data storage mechanism and this integration incurs costs based on the volume of data ingested into Log Analytics. There isn't a direct way to use Application Insights without Log Analytics, as metrics and logs collected by Application Insights are stored in Log Analytics by default. Unfortunately, as of September 2024, the tight coupling of Application Insights with Log Analytics means that completely avoiding Log Analytics costs is not feasible, unless you completely bypass Application Insights and set up custom logging

References:

Application Insights overview
Log-based and preaggregated metrics in Application Insights


Sigh. Other cloud vendors offer metrics & monitoring for free or at negligible pricing, but because Azure tied it to Log Analytics its actually very expensive. We will have to disable AppInsights completely in our project. It's curious that other services do offer these metrics without being tied to a Log Analytics, e.g., in EventHub I can see many monitoring metrics without incurring any Log Analytics usage. Hard to understand why this reliance on Log Analytics is mandatory for Function Apps.

As discussed over comments,it's not possible to avoid Log Analytics costs when using Azure Application Insights. The way Application Insights works is that it stores its telemetry and logs in Log Analytics, which leads to data ingestion charges based on the volume.
If you're already using another logging solution like Splunk through diagnostic settings, it can feel like you're being charged twice—once for logs stored in Log Analytics and again for logs sent to Splunk.
Workaround ways to reduce costs-

You can limit how much data is sent to Log Analytics by enabling sampling in Application Insights. This reduces the amount of telemetry data being ingested, which helps lower costs.

Reduce how long data is stored in Log Analytics can also lower the overall expense.

You can configure Diagnostic Settings to send logs straight to Splunk.


References:

Application Insights overview
Log-based and preaggregated metrics in Application Insights


That's a very genAI answer.

Simple answer is not possible :-) as mentioned in comment
